# Quarto Render not Rendering

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, quarto

I am trying out Quarto, I am using R version 4.2.1. When I go to RStudio, File -> New File -> Quarto Document and create a new document, when I try to render via the RStudio Render button, I get the error **'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable progam or batch file**

I have tried installing R in a directory which has no white space in the installation path, but this did not resolve the issue.

[image]

***UPDATE:*** on doing `quarto check` as suggested in comment gave me

[image]

Not sure what that means, but I was able to solve the problem by ensuring my `qmd` quarto file did not have white space in its name (replaced white space with underscores. The error then went away.

Comment: Please go to the terminal tab (next to jobs) and type: `quarto check`.   Then  edit the results into your original questions.

Answer (score 7):

On changing my `qmd` file name, from `HVL campaign.qmd` to `HVL_campaign.qmd` (removing the white space), the rendering works. The error message was misleading though, that may need to get looked at...?

Answer (score 6):

This error pops up if there is a space anywhere in the filepath unfortunately. I am running into this error when I try to make a new project in a directory that has a filepath with a space (thanks onderive...)